# jsonReader and jqgrid not populating json onto grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid, jsonreader

I have the json below and I am trying to get is display onto my jqgrid. I have the following jsonReader

```
jsonReader : {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: "abc",
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
        },
```

**column model:**

```
colModel:[
            {name:'num'},
            {name:'seq'},
            {name:'status'},
            {name:'transTime'},
            {name:'sd'},    
            {name:'total'},
            {name:'xys'}
        ],
```

**Json:**

```
{
    "xys": 3,
    "abc": [
        {
            "time": null,
            "num": "1234",
            "seq": 2,
            "status": "X",
            "transTime": null
        },
        {
            "time": null,
            "num": "4567",
            "seq": 1,
            "status": "Y",
            "transTime": null
        }
    ],
    "sd": "7895",
    "total": 5
}
```

only the num, seq and status got populated with data, but not transTime, sd, total and xys

any ideas and pointer?

Comment: `sd`, `total` and `xys` are not a property of `abc` array. How you want to display the items in the grid? Duplicate in every row in the corresponding column? `transTime` is empty and will be not displayed as "null" string, just as an empty string "".

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I want to display all of the data coming back in that JSON. I want to display the xys, sd, total and abc array onto the grid. I understand that time and transTime is null so they do not get display. I want to be able to display xys, sd, and total along with abc array

Comment: The most easy way would be to place `sd`, `total` and `xys` properties as the properties of `abc` items. You can additionally change `"transTime": null` to `"transTime": "null"`. Do you can do this on the server side? If not, then one can do the changes of input data *on the client side* inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. If you will have implementation problems I can show you how one can do this.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! Can you please show me how? JSON returns from server is fixed and I cannot make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *have to* read the JSON data and can't change the data on the server side you can makes small transformation of the data returned from the server *on the client side* inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3420947.htm) do this and displays the following results

[image]

It uses the following code

```
loadonce: true,
jsonReader: { root: "abc" },
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var root = data.abc, i, item, cItems = root.length;
    for (i = 0; i < cItems; i++) {
        item = root[i];
        item.sd = data.sd;
        item.id = $.jgrid.randId();
        item.total = data.total;
        item.xys = data.xys;
        if (item.transTime === null) {
            item.transTime = "null";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oleg, I am getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined jquery.jqGrid.min.js:66

Comment: @user3420947: **Which version of jqGrid you use?** I included `item.id = $.jgrid.randId();` line in the code, but it's not required. You should always use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` if you have an error and post the line number in SRC-version of jqGrid.

Comment: I use jquery.jqGrid.min.js version 4.2.0. I changed to jquery.jqGrid.src.js and I still get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined jquery.jqGrid.src.js:1281

Comment: @user3420947: I suppose that you don't used `item.id = $.jgrid.randId();` line in `beforeProcessing`. I don't recommend you to use so old version of jqGrid. It was published in 2011. In any way [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3420947_.htm) works too with jqGrid 4.2.0. If you will still have the same error with your data you can include `cell: false` property in `jsonReader`.